# how to extract the csv file and store as a text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I wrote a code for this which will convert the csv to a text files in the destination folder. So I thought to share if this can help someone. And feel free to say the better way if you have, I love to learning better ways.

```
text_reader1 = csv.reader(open('C:/Users/nkumarn/PycharmProjects/product.csv', newline = ""))
print(text_reader1)
count = 1
for row in text_reader1:
    filename = "text"
    ext=".txt"
    path = "C:/Users/nkumarn/PycharmProjects/CVSFiles/vRA/"
    file = open(path + "%s" % (filename+str(count)+ext,), "w")
    file.write(row[0])
    file.close()
    count +=1
```

Comment: just rename it to .txt? :)

Comment: If what you want is just a better way to write some working code, then the right place is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: do you want to read csv file at a time and to write it to a text file?

Comment: yeah that what I tried

Comment: vivek kalyanarangan : the csv file has lot of rows, and if each data in the row need to be taken as a text file, I think code works.

Comment: Thank you ettanany:  I wasn't aware of that. I will check it out and write my code there from next time :)

Comment: @ettanany as it is, the question lacks context and it'll probably be closed as off-topic on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/nkumarn/PycharmProjects/product.csv')
np.savetxt('C:/Users/nkumarn/PycharmProjects/r.txt', df.values, fmt='%2f')
```